# What does each sample in kAudioFormatLinearPCM represent?

Tags: ios4, ios5, core-audio

I figured out that the default setting on my device for audio is kAudioFormatLinearPCM.

I get 4 bytes per sample in mData in the AudioBuffer.

Is each value an absolute amplitude value?  Is it always a positive number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the stream format.  If the format is unsigned then the value is always positive.  If the sample format is signed, then the value can be either positive or negative.

The value may also need to be byte-swapped, depending on the endianness of the format, the endianness of the processor (little-endian on ARM iOS), and how the value is read from the stream, for the value to be a linear amplitude value.

Answer (score 0):

> Is each value an absolute amplitude value?

Yes.

> Is it always a positive number?

It's variable across the APIs and implementations you will encounter. You will have to refer to other fields of the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` to determine the sample format and stream precisely.